# Convert hex value to decimal in C but keep getting incorrect value, plus too few argument error when calling func

Tags: c, binary, hex

Hello I am trying to convert a hex value into the decimal form but for some reason the result I'm getting each time is negative and completely incorrect. Additionally I would like to take that decimal number and then convert it into it binary value. I have created func's for both but have run into the problem of "too few arguments" when calling my `bin()` func. If somebody could point me in the right direction and explain what I am doing wrong I would sincerely appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define arraysize 20

int decimal() {

    int i = 0, val, len;
    char hex1[arraysize];
    long long dec = 0, base = 1;

    len = strlen(hex1);

    for (i = len--;i >= 0; i--) {
        if (hex1[1] >= '0' && hex1[i] <= '9') {
            dec += (hex1[i] - 48) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if (hex1[i] >= 'A' && hex1[i] <= 'F') {
            dec += (hex1[i] - 55) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if (hex1[i] >= 'a' && hex1[i] <= 'f') {
            dec += (hex1[i] - 87) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
    }
    printf("Your decimal value is: %lld\n",dec);
    return 0;
}

int bin(long long dec) {

    int a[10], i;

    for (i = 0; dec > 0; i++) {
        a[i] = dec % 2;
        dec = dec / 2;
    }
    printf("\nThe binary value is: ");
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    char hex1[arraysize];

    printf("Enter your HEX value: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(hex1, arraysize, stdin);

    decimal(hex1);
    bin();
}
```

Comment: The best advice would be to learn how to debug your own code. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it to trace it's execution flow and variable values. As for the second problem you are obviously missing a required arg in the `bin()` call which takes one arg.

Comment: The `decimal` function does not take a parameter yet there is one passed. The `bin` functions expects a parameter but none is passed. The `decimal` function doesn't work because the function does not accept the string that is input and instead it tries to convert an uninitialized array.

Comment: @fishbrains This call len = strlen(hex1); invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @fishbrains: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `hex1` should be passed as an argument to `decimal()`. As posted, your code has undefined behavior because `hex1` is an uninitialized local array.
- `i = len--` initializes `i` to the value of `len`, hence one position too far. Use `i = len - 1` instead.
- `if (hex1[1] >= '0' && hex1[i] <= '9')` uses `hex[1]` instead of `hex[i]`
- you should use expressions with character constants `'0'`, `('A' - 10)` and `('a' - 10)` instead of hard coded magical values `48`, `55` and `87`.
- the array `a` is too short in function `bin()`. You should give it a length of at least 64.
- the argument in `bin()` should have `unsigned long long` type.
- `fflush(stdin);` has undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long decimal(const char *hex) {
    unsigned long long dec = 0;
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0; (c = hex[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            dec = dec * 16 + (c - '0');
        } else
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
            dec = dec * 16 + (c - 'A' + 10);
        } else
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
            dec = dec * 16 + (c - 'a' + 10);
        }
    }
    return dec;
}

void bin(unsigned long long dec) {
    char a[65];
    int i;

    a[64] = '\0';
    for (i = 63;; i--) {
        a[i] = '0' + dec % 2;
        dec = dec / 2;
        if (dec == 0)
            break;
    }
    printf("The binary value is: %s\n", a);
}

int main() {
    char hex1[20];

    printf("Enter your HEX value: ");
    if (fgets(hex1, sizeof hex1, stdin)) {
        unsigned long long dec = decimal(hex1);
        printf("Your decimal value is: %llu\n", dec);
        bin(dec);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RetiredNinja: yes indeed, answer updated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The "too few arguments" error means exactly what it says: you are calling the `bin()` function with no arguments. In your function definition, you defined `bin()` as taking a `long long dec` argument. When you call `bin()`, you must give it an argument, like

```
bin(7);
```

---

You have made the opposite mistake in the line above:

```
decimal(hex1);
```

You defined `decimal()` as taking no arguments, yet you called it with a `char[]` argument. In your `decimal` function you can remove the line where you declare an array of `char`s, and instead make that an argument of the function:

```
int decimal(char* hex1) {

    int i = 0, val, len;
    long long dec = 0, base = 1;
    
    . . .
```

You may want to further research the semantics of passing an array as an argument to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and replace `char hex1[arraysize]="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";` as needed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define arraysize 20
#define bin_arraysize 64

unsigned long long decimal(char* hex1) {

        long long dec = 0, base = 1;
        int len = strlen(hex1);
        for(int i = len-1;i >=0; i--) {
               if(hex1[i] >= '0' && hex1[i] <= '9') {
                        dec += (hex1[i] - 48) * base;
                        base *= 16;
               }
                else if(hex1[i] >= 'A' && hex1[i] <= 'F') {
                        dec += (hex1[i] - 55) * base;
                        base *= 16;
                }
               else if(hex1[i] >= 'a' && hex1[i] <= 'f') {
                       dec += (hex1[i] - 87) * base;
                       base *= 16;
               }
        }
        printf("Your decimal value is: %llu\n",dec);
        return dec;
}


void bin(unsigned long long dec) {

        int a[bin_arraysize], i;

        for(i = 0; dec > 0; i++) {
                a[i] = dec%2;
                dec = dec/2;
        }
        printf("\nThe binary value is: ");
        for(i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                printf("%d", a[i]);
                }
        return;
}

int main() {

        char hex1[arraysize]="FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";  
        unsigned long long dec=decimal(hex1);
        bin(dec);
}
```